# Dynamic construction of React component with Typescript annotations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created a short demo for the demonstration. The point is, I want to create React components using my own `customCreate` service. But I want to check the properties of the input component. When I declared the inputs in customCreate to `any`, everything is fine, but there is no type check by Typescript.

My condition is the ability to create different components using customCreate.

What types should I set in the customCreate function to make everything work properly with type checking? Thanks

```
interface IDemoObjectProps {
    demoprop1: string,
    demoprop2: number
};

class DemoComponent extends React.Component<IDemoObjectProps> {
    render() {
        return <></>
    }
}

// Annotation?
const customCreate = (type: any, props: any) => {
    return React.createElement(type, props);
};

// Create React element
const component1 = customCreate(DemoComponent, {demoprop1: 'demo', demoprop2: 2022});
console.log(component1);
```

Comment: If you want to preserve all function overload signatures check [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLq9bW) example